# In the Following Code for Stopwatch using javascript, html, css the Reset Button is not working properly what should be done to solve the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the output of this code the reset button does resets the values of min sec milisec to 0 but when I again play the stopwatch the values of min sec milisec doesnt start from 0 whereas it starts from the previously paused values

while pressing the reset button the values are not reset properly and it starts from the previously paused values

```js
const playButton = document.getElementsByClassName("play")[0];
const lapButton = document.getElementsByClassName("lap")[0];
const resetButton = document.getElementsByClassName("reset")[0];
const clearButton = document.getElementsByClassName("lap-clear-button")[0];
const minute = document.getElementsByClassName("minute")[0];
const second = document.getElementsByClassName("sec")[0];
const centisecond = document.getElementsByClassName("msec")[0];
const laps = document.getElementsByClassName("laps")[0];
const bg = document.getElementsByClassName("outer-circle")[0];

let isPlay = false
let secCounter = 0;
let min;
let sec;
let centiSec;
let centiCounter = 0;
let minCounter = 0;
let lapItem = 0;
let isReset = false;


const toggleButton = () => {
  lapButton.classList.remove("hidden");
  resetButton.classList.remove("hidden");
}

const play = () => {
  if (!isPlay && !isReset) {
    playButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';
    bg.classList.add("animation-bg");
    min = setInterval(() => {

      minute.innerHTML = `${++minCounter} :`;

    }, 60 * 1000);
    sec = setInterval(() => {
      if (secCounter === 60) {
        secCounter = 0;
      }
      second.innerHTML = `&nbsp;${++secCounter} : `;

    }, 1000);
    centiSec = setInterval(() => {
      if (centiCounter === 100) {
        centiCounter = 0;
      }
      centisecond.innerHTML = `&nbsp;${++centiCounter} `;

    }, 10);
    isPlay = true;
    isReset = true;
  } else {
    playButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
    clearInterval(min);
    clearInterval(sec);
    clearInterval(centiSec);
    isPlay = false;
    isReset = false;
    bg.classList.remove("animation-bg");

  }
  toggleButton();
}

const reset = () => {
  isReset = true;
  play();
  lapButton.classList.add("hidden");
  resetButton.classList.add("hidden");
  second.innerHTML = '&nbsp;0 :';
  centisecond.innerHTML = '&nbsp;0';
  minute.innerHTML = '0 :';

}

const lap = () => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const number = document.createElement("span");
  const timeStamp = document.createElement("span");

  li.setAttribute("class", "lap-item ");
  number.setAttribute("class", "number");
  timeStamp.setAttribute("class", "time-stamp");

  number.innerText = `#${++lapItem}`;
  timeStamp.innerHTML = `${minCounter} : ${secCounter} : ${centiCounter}`;

  li.append(number, timeStamp);
  laps.append(li);

  clearButton.classList.remove("hidden");
}

const clearAll = () => {
  laps.innerHTML = ' ';
  laps.append(clearButton);
  clearButton.classList.add("hidden");
  lapItem = 0;
}
playButton.addEventListener("click", play);
resetButton.addEventListener("click", reset);
lapButton.addEventListener("click", lap);
clearButton.addEventListener("click", clearAll);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Stopwatch</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="watch">
      <div class="outer-circle">
        <div class="inner-circle">
          <span class="text minute">0 :</span>
          <span class="text sec">&nbsp;0 :</span>
          <span class="text msec">&nbsp;0</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button class="button reset hidden">Reset</button>
        <button class="button play">Play</button>
        <button class="button lap hidden">laps</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="laps">
      <button class="lap-clear-button hidden">Clear All</button>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
secCounter = minCounter = centiCounter = 0;
```

to the `reset()` function so the counters are reset to 0.

Your code is just putting `0` in the spans, but the interval functions use these variables when updating the display.